# domain_force - Odoo group security read all records in custom module

Tags: xml, odoo

I'm trying to assign a security group (`group_user`) permission to be able to view all the records generated by the users of the group (`name_group_info_med`)

**user_group:** Can see all the records generated by group_name_information_medium_medical
**group_name_info_med:** can only see the records generated by it

The **acces_rules.xml** is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<odoo>
<data noupdate="0">

<record id="info_arch_user_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">See all</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_info_med"/>
    <field name="domain_force">
        [('create_uid', '=', user.id)]
    </field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('informed.group_user'))]"/>
</record>     

<record id="info_med_user_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Informe Medico  only for owners</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_info_med"/>
    <field name="domain_force">
        [('create_uid', '=', user.id)]
    </field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('informed.group_name_info_med'))]"/>
</record> 

</data>
</odoo>
```

Any suggestion of help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a group to have access to view all records (no restriction), then your record rule should use a `domain_force` of `[(1, '=', 1)]`.

```
<record id="info_arch_user_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">See all</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_info_med"/>
    <field name="domain_force">
        [(1, '=', 1)]
    </field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('informed.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

[Record Rules Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/security.html#record-rules) is pretty sparse, but you can view examples in the core code or in the Odoo backend (**Settings > Technical > Record Rules**).

---

**Disclaimer: This is to have a group be able to view *all* records, not just records of a different group. As @CZoellner mentioned in a comment below, that wouldn't be possible to do with Record Rules alone.**

Comment: Maybe the question is written wrong, but that is not the correct answer, if group a should see all records created by another group. That requirement can't be done by record rules, but only with programming like overriding the search method. Your solution is for group a seeing ALL records which of course includes the other requirement.

Comment: @CZoellner Good point. Since it was accepted, I guess the answer wasn't written clearly, but I added a disclaimer onto my answer to hopefully clarify that it isn't an answer to exactly what was asked.